# PDO fetch in Twig

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, twig

I take data from DB through PDO and I can't show all of data in HTML with Twig, but only first row showed. Help, please.

```
function listOfTasksWithSort ($pdo, $user,$sortStyle) {
$sortStyleOrder = isset($sortStyle) ? $sortStyle : '';
if (empty($sortStyleOrder)) {
    return $pdo->query("SELECT id, user_id, assigned_user_id, description, is_done, date_added FROM task WHERE user_id = '$user'");
} else {
    return $pdo->query("SELECT id, user_id, assigned_user_id, description, is_done, date_added FROM task WHERE user_id = '$user' ORDER BY $sortStyle ASC");
}
}

$listOfTasks = listOfTasksWithSort ($pdo, $_SESSION['userId'],$sortStyle);

$template = $twig->loadTemplate('index.tmpl');
echo $template->render(array(
'row' => $listOfTasks->fetch(),
));

{% for i in 1..10000 if row %}
{{ row.description }}
{% set row = false %}
{% endfor %}
```

Comment: It's `'row' => $listOfTasks->fetchAll()`, but you should really **really** use  prepared statements.

Comment: I learn on PHP classes and I don't know what it is. Could you show me, please?

Comment: http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php has some.

Comment: I have changed this:
"return $pdo->query("SELECT id, user_id, assigned_user_id, description, is_done, date_added FROM task WHERE user_id = '$user'");"
to this:
$query = $pdo->prepare("SELECT id, user_id, assigned_user_id, description, is_done, date_added FROM task WHERE user_id = ?");
$query->execute(array($user));
return $query->fetch(); 

but Twig again returns me 1 row

Comment: Like you've been told already you need [**fetchAll()**](https://phpdelusions.net/pdo#fetchall). You better pay attention to what people are telling you.

Comment: But you  didn't  change fetch to fetchAll,  did you?

Comment: Yes, you are right. Thank you.